# In Postgresql, how I tell a trigger Function to... IF NOT FOUND do nothing (pass)

Tags: function, triggers, postgresql-9.1

Im creating Trigger FUnctions with PostgreSQL 9.1, how I tell it in this Trigger Function...

```
IF NEW.timetype = 'start' THEN
  SELECT timestmp FROM tbl_ebscb_saaaa_log WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND timetype = 'start' ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_timestmp_start;
    IF FOUND THEN
      NEW.timetypespan := age(NEW.timestpm, v_timestmp_start);
    ELSE
    END IF;
```

I would like to... IF NOT FOUND then do nothing (like "pass" in python), what do I do? just leave it in blank??? Is not inside any loop.

Thanks Advanced.

PD: please if some could provide a good link with examples about basic postgresql work flow. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this in SQL generally:

First way is to not retrieve the value, but just check it. This would replace your select statement with an if [exists](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html) statement. Use this method if you don't need to do anything else with the `v_timestmp_start` value.

It would look like: `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE ...) THEN ...`.

The other way would be to check the value of the variable which should be NULL if the select did not find anything. This would look very much like what you already have (but replace found with [`IF NOT NULL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparison.html)).

This would look like: `IF v_timestmp_start IS NOT NULL THEN ...`.

And one more option that is unique to postgres. This looks exactly like what you already have [(`IF FOUND THEN ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)).

Comment: Thanks @davidpricedev, I edited like this... `IF EXISTS (SELECT timestmp FROM tbl_ebscb_saaaa_log ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1) THEN NEW.timestmpspan := age(NEW.timestmp, v_timestmp_start);` please notice this last `v_timestmp_start` so I guess I will be needing `v_timestmp_start` variable, So I guess the IF EXISTS method can't be applied, am I wrong?

Comment: Technically postgres is populating the `FOUND` variable with true/false for you and `IS NOT NULL` is a comparison operator that it must resolve to true/false, so there may be a slight performance benefit to the `FOUND` option.